# Can't find `combineLatest` in RxJS 5.0

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

The following code it's causing me a `Observable.combineLatest is not a function` using RxJS 5.0:

```
let Observable = require('rxjs/Observable.js').Observable;
import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest';

Observable
.combineLatest([player, spaceShip], (shotEvents, spaceShip) => ({
    x: spaceShip ? spaceShip.x : board.canvas.width / 2,
    timestamp: shotEvents.timestamp
}))
```

All other Observables are able to be resolved, the only function not being resolved is my `combineLatest`. I tried `observables/combineLatest` just for the sake of trying to no avail.

I'm compiling everything using `webpack` and `babel`, and the code is able to resolve `scan`, `range`, `interval`, `map`, and some others. Even `flatMap` using `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';` worked.

But not `combineLatest`

So if anyone has a working example it would be deeply appreciated. Couldn't find anything else in the docs besides [a unit test that is basically the same thing (an array of observables and a function).](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/spec/operators/combineLatest-spec.ts)

## UPDATE APR 04 2018

On RxJs 5.5 use the following:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest'
```

Moving forward (RxJs 6) use the following:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs'
```

Comment: guess I'll use `es6` exclusively or `typescript` exclusively

Comment: I'm having this same issue.

Comment: Not to just +1 this post, but I'm working with Typescript and having the exact same problem. Using webpack my code compiles fine, but at run-time this function just isn't there for some reason. Other operators work without any issues.

Comment: **import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs'** worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think [#1722](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1722) is the relevant GitHub issue here.

I'm on a project using `typescript@2.0.10`, `RxJS@5.0.3`, and `webpack@2.1.0-beta.25`. The following works for me:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';

Observable.combineLatest(
  source1,
  source2
).subscribe(sink);
```

Answer (score 9):

To me this seems like a bug related to [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/1193).

Two potential workarounds:

1. Instead of `import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest';`, use `import rxjs/rx`. This will register all operators (including `combineLatest`) to `Observable`.
2. Assign the imported function manually to the prototype:
   `let Observable = require('rxjs/Observable.js').Observable;`
   `Observable.prototype.combineLatest = require('rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest');`

Comment: The first workaround made it work for me.  import 'rxjs/rx';  using rxjs package version 5.0.3

Comment: @MichaelLang please be aware that this will actually import all of rxjs, ie including all operators. Hence your bundle size will increase by a few 100kB! better tale the second option!

Comment: @PeterAlbert Ok serious question here. I've been importing rxjs across all my apps without `rxjs/Rx`. I've been told that it increases size. But how relevant is that increase anyway? I have like 3-5 lines of import functions for rxjs in my components. Developer happiness goes down when there's so many import functions.

Comment: @KaMok While developer happiness might increase, the bundle size of your application will increase - and hence user happiness might decrease. Also, the build time will increase, as the build task has to process the whole RX library. For details, check https://christianliebel.com/2017/07/import-rxjs-correctly/ - they have some stats on the impact, so you can decide if it is worth the tradeoff.

Comment: @KaMok Refer to studies about performance to find out `how relevant is size increase?` https://www.doubleclickbygoogle.com/articles/mobile-speed-matters/

Answer (score 8):

I'm on RXJS 5.5.6, to import `combineLatest` for direct use (not as an operator) I had to use:

```
import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved the problem for me

import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';

I am using rxjs v6

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you went that route instead of `import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs'`

Comment: Yes  import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs didn't work for me. But I solve the problem by running npm install for the second time. Thanks

Comment: thanks, I was curious, a lot of effort by many people was done to import this way

Answer (score 0):

If combineLatest is not working try the following:

> npm install --save rxjx-compat

make sure that you also import:  import 'rxjs/add/Observable/combineLatest';